# Serve multiple Django static directories with Apache

Tags: django, apache, httpd.conf

Is there a way to serve 2 or more static directories from Apache? I am using Django and it works fine with 1 static path; when I put 2 it ignores the 2nd.

I don't want to use collecstatic. Just trying to setup my development environment and I like to keep my statics in each app separately. I know in production this will change.

Here is my Apache httpd.conf code:

```
#games app
Alias /static/ "C:/nerd_project/nerd/games/static/"
<Directory "C:/nerd_project/nerd/games/static">
Require all granted
</Directory>

#ice_cream app
Alias /static/ "C:/nerd_project/nerd/ice_cream/static/"
<Directory "C:/nerd_project/nerd/ice_cream/static">
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

games app works; the css and images load

ice_cream app does not load and is ignored

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to Alias same URL path `/static/` to two directories. That's why it's failing.

Django has pretty fine documention on [Serving static files during development.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Check [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) settings docs to serve static files from multiple directories.

If you are trying to serve multiple projects static you may consider VirtualHost.

Comment: Yes, I have read all that on the official documentations. It never mentioned 2 directories though, so I was assuming it was not possible. Also how do we go about with using VirtualHost? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to serve multiple site or single site with multiple app?

Comment: A single site with multiple apps. Each app has it's own static folder.

Comment: The STATICFILES_DIRS seams to be only useful if you use collecstatic which I don't want to use. Perhaps the VirtualHost is the only way?

Comment: No way to alias more than one directory? Seams pretty simple. I just want Apache to be able to serve several static folders. This is stricly development and of course not production.

Comment: This'll work for static file serving view as well. From docs: " This setting defines the additional locations the staticfiles app will traverse if the FileSystemFinder finder is enabled, e.g. if you use the collectstatic or findstatic management command or **use the static file serving view** "

Comment: You can alias as many directories you want. The problem is with same URL path.

Comment: Hmm.. so I can add the 2 directories to the STATICFILES_DIRS and keep the alias the same? Also what is the "static file serving view"?

Comment: Yes, 2 or more directories. static view is builtin `django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()` view. Check the docs on first link again.

Comment: Ok this looks like it would work for development. But now then I don't need to configure the httpd.conf at all? I can completely ignore the alias it seams.

Comment: Yes, the apache are bits are not needed during development.

Comment: Yeah, I did all the configs but it seams that this doesn't work with Apache. CSS won't load. I specifically need Apache to be the main server and not the "runserver" command.

Comment: Thank you @moonstruck. I am posting the exact answer. You pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same problem till today morning and landed on this page to understand why my static file configs were failing.

You can serve multiple apps with multiple static locations.
See how I have two Flask app and one Django app running and static files being served from different locations for all.

ServerName ec2-52-20-211-238.compute-1.amazonaws.com

```
# logs configuration
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

WSGIDaemonProcess aira  threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /aira /var/www/aira/aira/aira/aira.wsgi
Alias /aira/static/ /var/www/aira/aira/aira/static/
<Directory /var/www/aira/aira/aira/>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess ama threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /ama /var/www/AMA/ama.wsgi
Alias /ama/static/ /var/www/AMA/static/
<Directory /var/www/AMA>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess realestatesurvey threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /RealEstateSurvey /var/www/RealEstateSurvey/mydata/wsgi.py
Alias /RealEstateSurvey/static/ /var/www/RealEstateSurvey/mydata/static/
<Directory /var/www/RealEstateSurvey/mydata/static>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

For flask template just use

For Django:
STATIC_URL = '/RealEsatateSurvey/static'
in html files:-

Answer (score 1):

I can give a much more easier way to solve this issue that I learned about recently.

If you don't want to serve your static files with Nginx or a apache, but from different apps or folders you can install a pip module called `whitenoise` in your virtual environment.

Refer this: [whitenoise docs](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/)

And then just add this in middlware before the sessionmiddleware in your settings.py file.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', # Serve static in production without nginx or apache
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
........
]
```

Then finally you can remove those `Alias` statements for rendering static files from your httpd.conf file. Make migrations and restart the server, your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out EXACTLY what needs to be done to serve multiple static directories using Apache.

This page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/ mentions this:

"Also this helper function **only serves the actual STATIC_ROOT folder**; it doesn’t perform static files discovery like django.contrib.staticfiles."

Adding `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to the urls.py did not load the css and images. You have to read a bit more carefully and go to this page:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve

I added the following to the my urls.py and now IT WORKS:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles import views

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', views.serve),
    ]
```

I simply commented out the alias and directories pointing to the 2 static directories in Apache's httpd.conf file.
Of course  this is strictly for a development server only as I like to keep my statics in each app.